# how to write a claim for this attachment

Tags: patentability, claims, patent-applications, claim-amendment

suppose I have two vertical panels that was attached with each other as image attached, could I write below.

**one vertical edge of the panel attached to another panel surface by appropriate meanings base on the material applied.**

is **attach** the broadest meaning than **connected**, is the claim too simple? thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: What does “meanings base” mean.

Comment: it should be" based on " if I am correct, just want to include methods as many as possible, material and process

Answer (score 1):

I would try something similar:

Claims:

1. A panel structure comprising a first panel and a second panel, wherein the main surface of the first panel is attached to the edge of the second panel.
2. The panel structure according to claim 1, wherein the second panel is substantially perpendicular to the first panel.
3. ..., wherein the first and second panels are made of plastic and are attached by glue.
4. ..., wherein the first and second panels are made of metal and are attached by soldering.

...

You may use synonyms in the description, and replace a word with its synonym later in a response to an Office Action if required.

Being vertical is not relevant as directions are not defined. For example: rotating the page 90° would result in up becomes left and down becomes right.

Comment: Thank you very much @picducor,  I am not sure how to write a broader claim that include many ATTACH method as possible, I see you write plastic, metal, but how about glass, wood etc... how do you solve it?  if vertical here is not a proper description, could I use " panel is disposed in a upright vertical position" to description this frame? I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: If you add that the panel can be made of anything, you do not add any additional information. You may try the dependent claim: "wherein the way of attachment is dependent on the material of the panel." But, at least in Europe, it wouldn't bring much, it has no inventive info in it.  

Regarding absolute directions, you would like to protect an object regardless its absolute position. Claiming a cup with an opening on the top, does not protect the cups laying on the side or upside down. Of course, if you claim a device with several parts, their relative position to each other is important.

Comment: Hi @picibucor, it is a device with several parts I am working with, I write some material on the description and I don't want to write specific material in claim if I can, the UK examiner think I am "ADD MATTER" in my claim, but I think it just a more specific description, I prefer ATTACHMENT DEPENDENDT ON MATERIAL APPLIED" since you know different material need different process and technology, furthermore, this is not the feature of the invention. I under estimate the complex of writing an application. it confused me what should be in the claim and what should be not. thanks alot